# Finding vmstat's swap (si/so) data anywhere in /proc

Tags: linux, proc

Is it possible to find (or derive) the amount of data swapped in our out per second from information contained in the /proc filesystem?  I'd like to get something like what vmstat provides in its si/so columns.

I've looked in /proc/meminfo, /proc/stat, and a handful of other locations but haven't seen anything promising.

Comment: I think `sar` gets this information from the `pswpin` and `pswpout` fields in the `/proc/vmstat` file.

Comment: It's a cumulative count but that just means you need to do some periodic sampling and some arithmetic to get the data down to a time interval.

Comment: @Bratchley this seems to be what I'm looking for.  If you submit your comment as an answer I will accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think `sar` gets this information from the `pswpin` and `pswpout` fields in the `/proc/vmstat` file. It's a cumulative count but that just means you need to do some periodic sampling and some arithmetic to get the data down to a time interval.